# docker pull/login always using http instead of https

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I installed a docker in ubuntu live 22.04 which installed on vmwrae. And I set the docker daemon.json like this

```json
{
  "registry-mirrors" : [
    "https://my-domain.com"
  ],
  "insecure-registries": [
  ]
}
```

Which `https://my-domain.com` is my private registry, and It is installed on another machine.
But when I use docker pull or login my private registry, docker always use http instead of https

```
root@root:~# docker pull my-domain.com/example/hello-world
Error response from daemon: Get "http://my-domain.com/v2/": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused

root@root:~# docker login my-domain.com
Username: ******
Password: ******
Error response from daemon: Get "http://my-domain.com/v2/": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
```

Why does my docker always use http instead of https? I haven't set the relevant configuration.

this is my docker info:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-docker)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.14.1)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.23.0)

Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 2
 Server Version: 20.10.22
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 9ba4b250366a5ddde94bb7c9d1def331423aa323
 runc version: v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.15.0-57-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 1
 Total Memory: 1.896GiB
 Name: suyj
 ID: HB2H:FWFC:GOZT:K7HR:EFLZ:Z6TM:MJCC:MS3W:EO44:NZ4G:W3WZ:TWGJ
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Registry Mirrors:
  https://my-domain.com/
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I know what happen with my docker.
I changed the configuration (`/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`) to fix the IP address of the virtual machine.

```yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: true
      optional: true
      addresses:
       - 192.168.188.137/24
      routes:
       - to: default
         via: 192.168.188.2
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 114.114.114.114
          - 8.8.8.8
        search:
          - localhost
          - local
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

But my domain name is intranet, not public. When I ping the private registry domain, it not return the right IP because it try to find the domain IP from public network.

```
root@root:~# ping my-domain.com
PING docker-iottest.midea.com(ip6-localhost (::1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms
```

I must be set vmware network gateway as DNS address to analyze.

```yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      ......
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.188.2  # add the vmware network gateway IP
          - 114.114.114.114
          - 8.8.8.8
        ......
```

When I reload the network or reload the system, it is work and return the correct IP.